How to bind a formarray of form groups from parent to child component in Angular?
Need help from anyone who has worked on angular reactive forms. I have a parent component and 3 child components
In the parent component, I have a form which looks like this :
parent form : 

formarray1 : formarray[5 formgroups]
formarray2 : formarray[5 formgroups]
formarray3 : formarray[5 formgroups]

Parent component pseudocode:
<form [formGroup] = "parentform">
      @for(i for index){ //loop runs 5 times
          <app-child1></app-child1> // bind array1
          <app-child2></app-child2> // bind array2
          <app-child3></app-child3> // bind array3
       }
</form>

In the child component, there are form controls and validations done for the specific Formgroup.
How should I bind the 3 formarrays to the 3 child components in such a way that for every loop run, the "i"th formgroup in the formarray is bound with the "i"th child component rendered in the parent component?

You can either just pass it in as an input. Make sure to not call it "formGroup" though or your child components implement the FormControlValueAccessor than you can use the [formGroup] binding from ReactiveFormsModule.
But just for a child view I would go with the first option
<form [formGroup] = "parentform">
      @for(i for index){ //loop runs 5 times
          <app-child1 [_formGroup]="parentform.controls[i].formarray1"></app-child1> // bind array1
          <app-child2 [_formGroup]="parentform.controls[i].formarray2"></app-child2> // bind array2
          <app-child3 [_formGroup]="parentform.controls[i].formarray3"></app-child3> // bind array3
       }
</form>


Two questions here. 1. Correct me if I'm wrong but as per the answer, if I'm passing the formgroup from parent to child components using @input, I should not use the [formGroup] in any of the child component template tags. Am I right? 2. Do the changes made in the child component reflect in the parent form?

What I meant with that is to not use <app-child1 [formGroup]="..."> but instead to use a different name for the input property, e.g. [_formGroup]=".." or [childForm]="..."

And yes you are passing the formGroup instance and all changes inside the child are reflected in your parent component
